# Hazard function for a growing population

Tags: survival, reliability, hazard, weibull-distribution

I want to model the expected failure rate in a growing population.

Each individual has a high infant mortality (e.g. `Weibull(shape=0.5, scale=100)`).

So the failure rate (or hazard function) at time t, `H(t)`, is the density function divided by the survival function: `H(t) = pdf(t)/sf(t)`

The complication is that at every timestep, I have many individuals in my population. They have different age, and therefore different expected failure rates, which is given by their hazard function `h(t)`. The expected failure rate of the population as a whole is a mix of these hazard functions. How do I compute that?

My first instinct was to sum up densities and survival functions individually, and then divide one by the other.

```
pdfs = numpy.zeros(max_time)
sfs = numpy.zeros(max_time)
for t in individual_start_times:
    ts = numpy.arange(max_time-t)
    pdfs[t:] += scipy.stats.weibull_min.pdf(ts, shape=0.5, scale=100)
    sfs[t:] += scipy.stats.weibull_min.sf(ts, shape=0.5, scale=100)
hazard = pdfs/sfs
```

Does that make sense, or is that bogus? I'm struggling to verify this.

Comment: As an epidemiologist reading "high infant mortality" is quite confusing: "high" implies that "infant mortality" which "high" intensifies is an infant mortality *rate*. However, *individuals* do not have mortality rates: they are either dead or alive (or sometimes  "kinda dead" or "mostly dead", c.f. S. Morgenstern)

Comment: @Alexis Well, an individual can be not even born yet, and still we can have expectations about their lifespan. In other words, consider an individual as a random variable, not as a particular outcome.

Suppose you know the dates at which kids will be born in an area, and you know the distribution of their lifespan. Then you have a probability of death at day t for a particular kid. But how do you get the expected death rate at day t of the entire population?

Comment: I would use "expected mortality risk" (or, if you care about life span "life expectancy").

Comment: Where you say "expected failure rate of the population as a whole" are you trying to calculate the distribution of the time to extinction (i.e. the expected time until the entire population is dead)?

Comment: No, I care about the expected failure rate. The expected number of deaths over expected number alive.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you could fit a Weibull model to your data with Age as the covariate/predictor. And then from this model extract the estimated hazard function. The following code illustrates how this can be done in R using the **survival** package:

```
library("survival")

# Accelerated Failure Time (AFT) Weibull model
fm <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ age, data = lung, dist = "weibull")
summary(fm)

# transform coefficients to Proportional Hazards (PH) scale
# (Weibull only model capable of having both AFT and PH formulations)
shape <- 1 / fm$scale
X <- model.matrix(fm)
scale <-  exp(- shape * c(X %*% coef(fm))) 

# function to calculate hazard function for 
# every subject in the data for a set of time points
ht <- function (time, shape, scale) {
    outer(shape * time^(shape - 1), scale) 
}

# A figure of the estimated hazard for the
# first 5 subjects
times <- seq(0.001, 1000, length = 500)
matplot(times, ht(times, shape, scale[1:5]), type = "l", lty = 1,
        xlab = "Follow-up Time (days)", ylab = "Estimated Hazard Function")
legend("bottomright", paste("Patients", 1:5), col = 1:5, lty = 1, bty = "n")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This isn't what I'm looking for though. I have the fitted Weibull distribution already, and I know the hazard function of this distribution. But for any time t, I have multiple things alive, and each thing has a different age and thus a different chance of failure at that time. So I have the expected chance of failure of each instance, and what I'm looking for is the expected failure rate of the entire population at time t.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Then would it work if you fitted the Weibull model without age as a predictor? This would give you one hazard function for the whole sample that would be an estimate of the hazard function of the entire population.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't have a sample I'm trying to fit to. I'm doing predictions about the future, so I have a rate at which new lifetimes start, each life follows the same Weibull distribution, and I want to draw conclusions about the global failure rate at any future time.